# Websphere 8.5 application server not been able to send message to Response Queue

Tags: java, ejb, ibm-mq, websphere-8, websphere-7

I am migrating an application from websphere application server 7.x to 8.5. Application is based on Java and EJB. When migrating the application I have recompiled the source code in Java 8 and deployed the application in 8.5 with same JNDI configurations as in 7.x. But I am facing an issue while sending resonse message into one external MQ getting 2085 MQRC_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_NAME error.

Same code is working fine in 7.x with Java 6 without any issue. Do I need to do any specific configuration in 8.5. Response Queue is Clustered Queue and its not configured in Client Application server its derived from MQ message.

Comment: Is this pointing to exactly same host and queue manager? Or some newly added to cluster queue manager? Was the response queue clustered in v7 configuration also? Did you check this [page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q041480_.html)

Comment: @gas yes Response Queue was clustered in v7 configuration as well. Also we haven't configured that response in Application Server JNDI.